# How to make it so it asks you what video player you'd like to use when trying to play a video in a Web View?

Tags: android, video, webview, video-player

I'm trying to make it so when you try to play a video in a web view it asks you what video player you'd like to use. Such as MX Player, or the default video player in android. I'm trying to do that so you don't have to play it inside the web view. If you could help me that'd be great!

Comment: To my knowledge, the OS will ALWAYS ask the user what video player the user would want to use when playing a video as long as the user DID NOT set a default media player for playing videos.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do anything, android handles this. Android finds all relevant video player applications and shows a choice dialog to user.

You can try with this code(put a movieUrl, maybe it is stored in your sd card):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(movieUrl));
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

What I did was just make it play the video inside the web view. Thanks a lot though guys.